# Change maven repo for Jenkins shared library

Tags: maven, jenkins, shared-libraries

Up until now I have only used java library available in the public central maven repo from my shared-library pom.xml, but now I want to use a java library that is deployed in our private nexus but I keep getting the error:

```
unable to resolve class com.somecompany.SomeClass
```

After some digging I came across this documentation:
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/

[image]

My issue is that I don't want to use the maven central repo at all but I want to use my nexus as a mirror repo of the central maven repo for security concerns.

I do already use the maven settings.xml when build an artifact from a pipeline using mvn command, I'm wondering if there is any way I could do the same in the shared-library?

**####################  UPDATED-1 ###################**

My Groovy class inside the Shared-Library:

```
import com.somecompany.collections.secret.vault.VaultClient

Map getSecrets() {

  VaultClient client = new VaultClient()
  Map test = client.getAllSecrets()
  return test
}
```

My pom.xml

```
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.somecompany</groupId>
      <artifactId>vault-secret-management</artifactId>
      <version>${vault.secret.management}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-ecr</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Finally my pipeline:

```
@GrabResolver(name='restlet', root='https://nexus.us.somecompany.com/repository/asa-coll-release-maven-hosted/')
@Grab(group='com.somecomapny', module='vault-secret-management', version='1.0.20')
@Library('jenkins-libraries@feature/DM-27548-try-to-use-vault-client-in-shared-library')

String projectName = '6562_GL_CYBERFINANCIAL_IIT_IAC'

pipeline {

  agent {
    label 'ecs-node'
  }
   environment {
       VAULT_ADDR = 'https://vault.uat.use1.crypto.aws.efx/'   
       VAULT_NAMESPACE = 'intl-collections/dev-use1'
       VAULT_SECRETS_PATH = 'kv-admin-console/admin-console'
       VAULT_MAX_RETRIES = 3
       VAULT_RETRY_INTERVAL = 10
       VAULT_ROLE = 'efx-cloud-ec2-developer-provisioner-role'
   }
    stages {
        stage('Hello') {
           steps {
               script {
                
                def secret = vaultHelper.getSecrets()
                println("result: "+secret)
               }
           }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error:

```
14:46:30  [Pipeline] // node
14:46:30  [Pipeline] End of Pipeline
14:46:30  org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
14:46:30  /mnt/jenkins-ebs/jenkins/jobs/cxs349-test-vault/builds/13/libs/jenkins-libraries/vars/vaultHelper.groovy: 1: unable to resolve class com.equifax.collections.secret.vault.VaultClient
14:46:30   @ line 1, column 1.
14:46:30     import com.equifax.collections.secret.vault.VaultClient
14:46:30     ^
14:46:30  
14:46:30  1 error
14:46:30  
14:46:30    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
14:46:30    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:958)
14:46:30    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:605)
14:46:30    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:554)
14:46:30    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
14:46:30    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
14:46:30    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:254)
14:46:30    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.recompile(GroovyClassLoader.java:761)
14:46:30    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:718)
14:46:30    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:787)
14:46:30    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:405)
14:46:30    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell$TimingLoader.loadClass(CpsGroovyShell.java:170)
14:46:30    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:405)
14:46:30    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:677)
14:46:30    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:787)
14:46:30    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:775)
14:46:30    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.global.UserDefinedGlobalVariable.getValue(UserDefinedGlobalVariable.java:57)
14:46:30    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.getProperty(CpsScript.java:135)
14:46:30    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.getProperty(InvokerHelper.java:174)
14:46:30    at groovy.lang.Closure.getPropertyTryThese(Closure.java:312)
14:46:30    at groovy.lang.Closure.getPropertyDelegateFirst(Closure.java:302)
14:46:30    at groovy.lang.Closure.getProperty(Closure.java:287)
14:46:30    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.getProperty(InvokerHelper.java:174)
14:46:30    at groovy.lang.Closure.getPropertyTryThese(Closure.java:312)
14:46:30    at groovy.lang.Closure.getPropertyOwnerFirst(Closure.java:306)
14:46:30    at groovy.lang.Closure.getProperty(Closure.java:295)
14:46:30    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.getProperty(InvokerHelper.java:174)
14:46:30    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.getProperty(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:456)
14:46:30    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.getProperty(DefaultInvoker.java:39)
14:46:30    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyAccessBlock.rawGet(PropertyAccessBlock.java:20)
14:46:30    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:29)
14:46:30    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
14:46:30    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.get(PropertyishBlock.java:74)
14:46:30    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$GetAdapter.receive(LValueBlock.java:30)
14:46:30    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(PropertyishBlock.java:66)
14:46:30    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor202.invoke(Unknown Source)
14:46:30    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
14:46:30    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
14:46:30    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
14:46:30    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
14:46:30    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
14:46:30    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
14:46:30    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
14:46:30    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:129)
14:46:30    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:268)
14:46:30    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
14:46:30    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:185)
14:46:30    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:402)
14:46:30    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$400(CpsThreadGroup.java:96)
14:46:30    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:314)
14:46:30    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:278)
14:46:30    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:67)
14:46:30    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
14:46:30    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:136)
14:46:30    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
14:46:30    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
14:46:30    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
14:46:30    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
14:46:30    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
14:46:30    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
14:46:30    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
14:46:30  Finished: FAILURE
```

**##################### UPDATE-2 (resolved) #########################**

Moving the @GrabResolver and @Grab to the actual groovy code inside Shared-Library instead of in the Jenkins pipeline did the trick :)

```
import com.equifax.collections.secret.vault.VaultClient
@groovy.lang.GrabResolver(name='restlet', root='https://nexus.us.equifax.com/repository/asa-coll-release-maven-hosted/')
@groovy.lang.Grab(group='com.equifax', module='vault-secret-management', version='1.0.20')

Map getSecrets() {

  VaultClient client = VaultClient.getInstance();
  Map test = client.getAllSecrets()

  return test

}
```

Comment: [Using multiple repositories](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-repositories.html), [Mirror repositories](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-mirror-settings.html). You can check settings.XML into your repo and specify on cmd line "mvn -s ./settings.xml" or use [config file provider](https://plugins.jenkins.io/config-file-provider/)

Comment: I'm not sure I have explained well, I know how to use maven and the settings.xml. My issue is how to use settings.xml when importing a share library inside a pipeline?

`@Library('jenkins-libraries@2.0.56')`

Comment: Jenkins will use grapes, which works similar to maven resolver once you configure [additional repositories](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/grape.html#Grape-SpecifyAdditionalRepositories). Or you can [configure Globally](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#global-shared-libraries) or [retrieve dynamically](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#dynamic-retrieval) from a git repo. Our shared libs are groovy and it works fine from repo.

Comment: I have added the grab but I still getting the issue, Please see the UPDATED-1 part of my question

Answer (score 0):

First you need a settings.xml file, which specifies your repositories (Link to your nexus instance). I assume you have such a file in your local development environment

After that you need to upload the settings.xml to jenkins, described [here](https://developer.here.com/documentation/ci_cd/white_paper/topics/jenkins-setup.html)

You also should consider using a new user on your nexus  with a name like 'jenkins' and not using your own login, as the Jenkins is accessing your Nexus repo.

Comment: I'm not sure I have explained well, I know how to use maven and the settings.xml. My issue is how to use settings.xml when importing a share library inside a pipeline? @Library('jenkins-libraries@2.0.56')

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED

I was focusing on using Maven to load the dependencies for my Shared-Library as I did so far where all the dependency where in maven central repo.

Then I have looked at the Grab documentation but I was using the `@GrabResolver` and `@Grab` inside the pipeline itself which was wrong( see the code I posted in UPDATE-1)

Moving the `@GrabResolver` and `@Grab` to the actual groovy code inside Shared-Library did the trick see UPDATE-2 in my original Question

Comment: Good for you figuring it out, glad could help. Recommend though, you rephrase the question as an elaborated question and make your answer as I'd you are a third-party answering it, with the inights you now know. Then mark as self-answered. That will better help others looking for answers.